# How to deal with infinite list view in React Native?

Tags: react-native

`React-Native` has its own `ListView` component, but it has bad performance when dealing with very large data list or infinite list view, according to [the docs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/499).

I wonder how applications using React Native deal with this problem.

Comment: Is the question how to deal with infinite lists or how to handle the performance aspect, once the dataset of the list gets large?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the current version of `React Native` is `0.57` and now we can use [`FlatList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) for large data list and long list or infinite scrolling list.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out react-native-paginatable-list (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@twotalltotems/paginatable-list) This library makes infinite scroll and pull-to-refresh out-of-box. And it stores the list items into the redux store, which is quite convenient if you are using redux in your app.